# Push failed android-studio project

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I am getting the following error while i am trying to push/pull to/from my github repository. I haven't touched my repository for 20 days now. Last time that I have checked I was not getting any error like that.

I tried followed this answer and I went to help->registry-> and i checked the git.use.builtin.ssh but nothing happend. I am still getting the error.

I would appreciate any help

**Push failed**

Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.askUsername(GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:55) at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:66) Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:851) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:848) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498) at org.apache.xmlrpc.DefaultXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(DefaultXmlRpcTransport.java:87) at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72) at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194) at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185) at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178) at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.askUsername(GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:52) ... 1 more remote: Repository not found. Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/@@@@@/@@@@.git/'

Answer (score 4):

You may try it like this image shot. Hope you get relief from this error. Thanks
[image: Git push error in Android studio]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete `C:\Users\"User"\.gitconfig` file and then enter your github credentials via Android Studio. Or via recommended way you can enter Authorization key to access your github profile.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal:

```
git config credential.helper store
```